# can i retrieve files as per its creation date using java?

Tags: java, io, filesystems

I want to retrieve files of particular creation date and read data from it to draw a plot how can I do that? I have tried nothing just want to know that if its possible in java or not?

Comment: Please try and post your approach, stackoverflow is for better make of programming, please try . And learn how to ask questions hear

Comment: Make a class with `File` and `Date (long)` as fields. You can use `lastModified()` to get the last edited date of file. Create a `ArrayList` of that and sort it using custom `comparator`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Labor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File dir = new File("path-to-dir");

        File[] listFiles = dir.listFiles(dateFilter());
    }

    private static FileFilter dateFilter() {

        return new FileFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                long yesterday = new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

                return file.lastModified() > yesterday;
            }
        };
    }
}
```